# What's the benefit of a fortune axe?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I just got an axe with Fortune III from an enchantment table, but couldn't figure out what would actually yield more drops from it.

Is there actually a use for a fortune axe?

Comment: I think apples from leaves and mushroom blocks, but I won't leave an answer cause im not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quora post:

> "
>
> - When used on leaves it increases the odds of receiving apples, sticks and saplings.
> - When used on vines (all kinds) it also increases the odds of receiving a drop, with the highest rate of 100% with a Fortune III Axe.
> - When used on grass and ferns it does not increase the chance of a drop, but does increase the amount of the drop by a factor of 2.
> - When harvesting beets, potatoes, wheat (seeds only), netherwart, melons sweet berries and carrots using a Fortune Axe increases the amount of items in the drop by 1 per level of Fortune up to the proscribed drop limits.
>
> "

[-Quora Post](https://www.quora.com/What-does-fortune-on-an-AXE-do-on-Minecraft#:%7E:text=%20What%20does%20fortune%20on%20an%20AXE%20do,amount%20of%20the%20drop%20by%20a...%20More%20)

This post is up to date and was last updated November 26 (2020)

Comment: In most of these, the tool has been changed to the hoe though. Is this still the case even though it's supposed to be the fortune on the hoe?

Comment: @Ben what do you mean "the tool has been changed to the hoe"?

Comment: In 1.16, they changed all plant-based tools of choice to the hoe over the axe

Comment: @Ben idk it was updated a week ago though

Comment: I might do some testing to see what results I get

Comment: Hoe may be the tool to harvest them fastest, but the Fortune effect applies the same regardless of the tool (as long as the tool is capable of producing any drops out of the item at all). Since Axe is "the right tool" for a pretty small number of blocks, it's particularly helpful when harvesting crops, as you're unlikely to break anything you didn't intend to.